# prove that $(2^k5^{k+1}+1,2^{n+1}5^k+1) \ne 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

prove that for any $k,n \in N$ we have $$(2^k5^{k+1}+1,2^{n+1}5^k+1) \ne 1$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to denote the common divisor by d, after I wrote that d divides the first term and d divides the second and after I subtracted

Comment: and I only got powers of 2 and 5

Comment: I'm somehow thinking of finding a common divider of the two

Comment: Have you tried any examples?  For $k=1,n=2$ we get $\gcd(2\times 5^2+1,2^3\times 5+1)=\gcd(51,41)=1$, no?

Comment: I think if I didn't make the wrong calculations that 3 is a common divisor

Comment: This question is wrong. You could make it correct though by saying that $n$ and $k$ have the same parity.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a typo: If you change $2^{n+1}5^k+1$ to $2^{n+1}5^n+1$, then $3$ is a common factor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is true: if $n = 2$, $k = 3$, then the two numbers are $1001$ and $5001$. Note that $5001 = 3 \cdot 1667$, while $1001 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$. The numbers are relatively prime.

**EDIT:** As Haran suggested, the statement is true for $n$ and $k$ being the same parity. The reason is that the common divisor is $3$. It is easy to see that $3$ divides $2^k 5^k+1 + 1$, because this is a number of form $500\cdots 001$ (all digits add up to six). To show that $2^{n+1} 5^k + 1$ is divisible by three, we can just take the expression modulo three. Note that 
$$5^k \mod 3 = 2^k \mod k \implies 2^{n + 1} 5^{k} \equiv 2^{n + k + 1} \mod 3$$
However, we can note that $n + k + 1$ is odd as $n$ and $k$ have the same parity. We can further note that $2$ raised to any odd power modulo $3$ is congruent to $2 \mod 3$. Since $2^{n+1} 5^k$ is always $2$ modulo $3$ when $n$ and $k$ have the same parity, it follows that $2^{n+1} 5^k + 1$ is divisible by $3$ when $n$ and $k$ have the same parity. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

Correcting a likely typo, I'll assume that the intended problem was:

> Prove that for any $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $(2^k5^{k+1}+1,2^{n+1}5^n+1) \ne 1$.

Working mod $3$, we get
$$
2^k5^{k+1}+1
\equiv
2^k2^{k+1}+1
=
2{\,\cdot\,}4^k+1
\equiv
2{\,\cdot\,}1^k+1
=
3
\equiv
0
$$
and similarly
$$
2^{n+1}5^n+1
\equiv
2^{n+1}2^n+1
=
2{\,\cdot\,}4^n+1
\equiv
2{\,\cdot\,}1^n+1
=
3
\equiv
0
$$
so $3$ is a common factor of $2^k5^{k+1}+1$ and $2^{n+1}5^n+1$.